# UITableViewController Background Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

How can I set an image for `UITableViewController`?

I have used many things but it doesn't help me to set the image as background

```
UIImageView* bgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]] autorelease];

[tableView.backgroundView addSubview:bgView];
```

And this

```
[[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = 
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];

self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[backgroundView release];
```

And

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = 
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

None of it worked for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

sets the `background` fill mode

```
[youTable setBackgroundView:
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

sets the `background` mode tile

```
[youTable setBackgroundColor:
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

Comment: I have test it in my project and it unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: my doubt is that you put a background color to cells, and these cover the background.

Comment: my cells are default i didn't changed the color must i change it to clear color or the default is clear?

Comment: remember that its a UITableViewController no a tableview

Comment: in viewDidLoad (for example) try to put: [self.tableView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @ "bg.png"]]];

then tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath try putting cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor], so you put the background and make transparent the cell, but remember it depends on what you put in. You need to also make transparent the background of various objects, take for example the UILabel etc. ..

Comment: it worked with me put there is a problem that the images only showing the top of its and repeat every cell i want the image display as one part all the image

Answer (score 4):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)tableViewController.view;
tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

```
tableView.backgroundView = 
  [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 
                                            topCapHeight:5.0]];
```

Comment: Good but explain it for better understanding of users.

Answer (score 1):

If all the aforementioned suggestions don't work, just do it this way (the approach I *always* use):

1. Create a UIViewController subclass.
2. In viewDidLoad add both an UIImageView and an UITableView as subviews.
3. Configure the tableView and implement the delegate methods. Set the background image in the imageView.

I think setting the backgroundView for a tableView can cause graphical errors (repeating images for each cell), so that's why I use the approach described here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tableviews background view to a UIImageView instance (property `backgroundView` of `UITableView`).

Answer (score 0):

Following code is works well for me.
Can you try following code:-

```
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
bgView.frame = self.view.frame;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also not able to set the `backgroundColor` of `UITableView` because it's a `UITableViewController`, my issue solved by this

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
```

As suggested by the "WhiteTiger".

Comment: you're developing for the iPad? iPad setBackgroundColor does not work, you have to use necessarily setBackgroundView

Comment: i am not using setBackgroundColor here , and i am working for iphone

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg2.png"]];
```

or

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg2.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating for Swift 4

The problem I was having was that I wanted to add a button and a background image to the UITableViewController. I added the button successfully, but every time I added the image container, it would replace the button instead of adding it below the button. So to get both, I added the following in the ViewWillAppear function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Add a background view to the table view
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "carbonfiber1.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView
}
```