# IOS - Have UITableViewCells scroll over UIView (like the shazam app)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView above my UITableView. When the user scrolls down I want the UIView to stay in place at the top of the screen and have the cells scroll over it. The first page of the Shazam app does what I want.

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        CGRect newframe = self.publicTopView.frame;
        newframe.origin.y = -self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
        self.publicTopView.frame = newframe;
}
```

}

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't do anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would set the `tableView.backgroundView` to your view, and then set your cells to be clear (or whatever transparency you like). This will allow the cells to move over the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a scrollView with a transparent background. Then add a subview to it that is not transparent and offset down a bit. Here's an overkill example. The TextureView is just so you can see that the background isn't moving.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface TextureView : UIView
@end
@implementation TextureView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.view.frame;
    CGFloat sectionHeight = 300;
    int numberSections = 3;
    CGFloat clearSpaceAtTop = 300;

    CGRect sectionsViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, clearSpaceAtTop, scrollViewFrame.size.width, sectionHeight * numberSections);
    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollViewFrame.size.width, CGRectGetMaxY(sectionsViewFrame));



    TextureView *backGroundView = [[TextureView alloc]initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    backGroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:backGroundView];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIView *sectionViewsParent = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:sectionsViewFrame];
    sectionViewsParent.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:sectionViewsParent];

    NSArray *colors = @[[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor purpleColor]];
    CGFloat spacer = 4;
    CGRect colorViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sectionsViewFrame.size.width, sectionHeight - spacer);
    for (UIColor *color in colors){
        UIView *sectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:colorViewFrame];
        sectionView.backgroundColor = color;
        [sectionViewsParent addSubview:sectionView];
        colorViewFrame.origin.y += sectionHeight;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UIView instance is called `iconView`, the UITableView instance is called `tableView`,
If your view controller is UIViewController.

```
[self.view addSubview:iconView];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
//and you need set tableView.background to transparent.
```

If your view controller is UITableViewController, read this question:

[UITableViewController Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066387/uitableviewcontroller-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

basically all you have to do is to use UIScrollView's contentInset property

```
let topInset = topViewHeight.constant //based on your needs
sampleTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

see my github sample [here](https://github.com/Benny-iPhone/Shazam-Style-TableView/tree/master)